# @media only screen not working

Tags: html, css

I have placed

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

in my header. I want a specific css for screen width 768px but my div with class `price-tag` is not taking style from

```
@media only screen (min-width:768px)  {.price-tag{left:180px;}}
```

If I write

```
@media (min-width:768px)  {.price-tag{left:180px;}}
```

it takes the style and applies it to all screen width. Am i doing this in wrong way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `and`.

This isn't valid:

```
@media only screen (min-width:768px)
```

It should be:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px)
```

**Applying to 768px specifically:**

If I've understood your comment correctly you'd like to apply styling to screens specifically at 768px wide. No lower; no higher. While I can't quite picture why such code would be useful or practical I can show you how to do it.

Combine min-width and max-width using the same value:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 768px) {
```

Comment: I did tried it also. It also applies css to all screen widths. How can i apply it to only screen width of 768px only or should I code for individual screen width ?